# Specify column width using tabularx Table environment

Tags: tabularx, column-width

I am working on a complex document in LaTeX and have various types of tables. I'd like the 2nd column wider and the 3rd column rather narrow. I tried different ideas with this code chunk `{c *6{>{}X}}`.

I am thinking something like this for width: 1st column 25pts, 2nd column 300pts, last column 80pts. The idea is, to define column widths right within the table environment, but not in the document preamble. I reviewed the `tabularx` manual, some posts here, I'd like to see a full example of the table syntax, below what I have.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
{\tabcolsep=0pt\def\arraystretch{1}
    \caption{caption} \label{tab:some-table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c *6{>{}X}}\midrule
        & \centering\hspace{-1in} some text & \centering\hspace{-0.75in} some text \tabularnewline\midrule 
        1 \hspace{12pt}  & some very very long text and much much more text & \multirow{5}{\linewidth}{some text}\tabularnewline 
        2 \hspace{12pt}  & some text  & \tabularnewline
        3 \hspace{12pt}  & some text   &  \tabularnewline
        4 \hspace{12pt}  & some text  &   \tabularnewline
        5 \hspace{12pt}  & some text &  \tabularnewline
        \midrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What about p type columns? They might be better suited if you want to manually define the column widths.

Comment: Please also explain why you define a total of 7 columns, while you table only seem to need 3. Aldo, what's the reason for a 0pt tabcolsep and the repeated hspace commands in the frdt column?

Comment: That's fine, whatever works. How would I need to do this? Thanks! 7 columns? I am not sure what this code chunk does "{c *6{>{}X}}"

Comment: p{25pt} p{300pt} p{80pt} in a regular tabular should work.

Comment: *6 would mean "repeat the following code/column specifier six times" . So you have six columns plus the one c type column which sums up to a total of 7

Comment: ok, what is the syntax to combine "p{25pt} p{300pt} p{80pt} " with "{c *3{>{}X}}" I am trying all kinds of combinations, the editor removed that I am a noob to Latex

Comment: @Could you please add the documentclass that you are using as well as the settings of the `geometry` package if you happen to use it? Any advice will be much easier then. Please also add, if the use of `\multirow` is in this case intentional.

Comment: Multirow on purpose, geometry no, here the full doc preamble: https://pastebin.com/vrrYJ3VV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three versions of your table. In the first one, I have used a regulat `tabular` environment with the column widths you specified in your question. However, the table is a lot larger than the textwidth (at least of a standard article class; indicated by the red lines). I therefore suggest to use `tabularx` with either one or two `X` type columns. Which of them is better depends on the contents of the actual table. I have also replaced two of the `\midrule` commands with `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` respectively. To horizontally center the column headers with respect to the corresponding columns, I have used the `\thead` command from the `makecell`package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
    \caption{caption} \label{tab:some-table}
    \begin{tabular}{p{25pt}p{300pt}p{80pt}}
    \toprule
        & \thead{some text} & \thead{some text} \\
    \midrule 
        1  & some very very long text and much much more text & \multirow{5}{*}{some text} \\ 
        2  & some text & \\
        3  & some text & \\
        4  & some text & \\
        5  & some text & \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
    \caption{caption} \label{tab:some-table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXX}
    \toprule
        & \thead{some text} & \thead{some text} \\
    \midrule 
        1  & some very very long text and much much more text & \multirow{5}{*}{some text} \\ 
        2  & some text & \\
        3  & some text & \\
        4  & some text & \\
        5  & some text & \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
    \caption{caption} \label{tab:some-table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXl}
    \toprule
        & \thead{some text} & \thead{some text} \\
    \midrule 
        1  & some very very long text and much much more text & \multirow{5}{*}{some text} \\ 
        2  & some text & \\
        3  & some text & \\
        4  & some text & \\
        5  & some text & \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Update with the `apa6` document class: I have used `\multirow{6}{=}{...}`. `6` is needed in order to vertically center the text since the contents of the column take up a total of 6 lines. `=` ensures that the text is only as wide as the corensponding column.

```
\documentclass[doc,natbib,floatsintext,12pt,noextraspace]{apa6}
\shorttitle{short title}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htbp] 
    \caption{caption} \label{tab:some-table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXX}
    \toprule
        & \thead{some text} & \thead{some text} \\
    \midrule 
        1  & some very very long text and much much more text & \multirow{6}{=}{some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text} \\ 
        2  & some text & \\
        3  & some text & \\
        4  & some text & \\
        5  & some text & \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ALMOST! I like the second one, however, in the 3rd column (multirow) the text does not wrap to match the columns width. I tried \\ between words but that gives an error. Hence, longer than 80pts text just runs into the right margin.Also, I would like the text in the right column vertically centered.

Comment: @togedo: I have added an update based on the second example. Hope this suits your needs.

Comment: YES 1000x thanks! Looks good, Latex reports a bad box Overfull \hbox but the table looks very good.

Comment: @togedo: You're welcome. Do you get the overfull box warning with the table from my answer or if you fill in yome actual contents?

Comment: Not from your answer, but when I fill in my contents. I have a feeling the combination of packages and/or my customization is causing this; I am also getting some other errors with titlesec and ragged2e, but could not solve those issues. PDF looks fine.

Comment: @togedo: Regarding "getting some other errors"  and "PDF looks fine": Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Regarding the errors you get: The `titlesec` package does not seem to work well with the `apa6` document class. Why did you decide to use `apa6`? Because you prepare a manuscript for publication with them? In that case, it might be better to leave the predefined style (regarding section title, headers...)  unchanged. If you use the class for a different kind, of document, consider switching to one of the standard classes (such as `article`)  instead. Modifying them to suit your needs is much easiser.

Comment: APA6 strict is needed, for a thesis. The article class does not work for me: I need Chapters, TOCs, Appendixes, no running heads. Will review it to make sure I have no errors.

Comment: @leandriis this is the BEST answer (not one of, literally the best) I found. For hours I tried to get a clean looking table to work until I found your detailed response. I love the rational you provided for use of additional packages. THANK YOU.